# Reputation for editing

Tags: support, suggested-edits

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you get +2 for an accepted edit "up to 1000 total per user."  Does that mean after 500 edits, you don't get +2 for editing, or after you have 1000 reputation from anything you don't get +2?  Why is there this limit anyway?  In my opinion it would only serve to prevent people from editing after they have +1000.  After people can edit without moderator review, I can see why they wouldn't get more reputation, but why is there this +1000 limit?

Comment: An additional point to notice: if your improvement isn't good enough and the post gets deleted eventually you will lose the 2 rep again.

Comment: I stopped getting the +2 once I got to 2000 points, even though I am yet to get to the 500 edited posts threshold. It is neither clear to me why these thresholds exist; once I get the 500 edits silver badge there will be no single incentive to keep editing posts...

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean after 500 edits, you don't get +2 for editing, or after you have 1000 reputation from anything you don't get +2?

After 500 approved suggested edits where you get +2, the system stops rewarding you with reputation.

> but why is there this +1000 limit?

This was meant so you don't only focus in editing and do other contributions to the system, like answering questions. Now, seriously, by that point you shouldn't care about shinning-imaginary-internet points, right?

Comment: Yes, we want people to make other contributions, but editing is still a contribution.

Comment: @FeldpauschAll4 yeah, but we won't be rewarding them. Seriously, 500 suggested edits and no questions or answers?

Comment: You should also, hopefully, not care anymore by that point.

Comment: @Seth A guess you're right.  Most privileges are unlocked by then and anyone who has edited 500 posts probably was not doing it for the reputation.